No consigo que javascript agregue el elemento al final o al inicio en mi tabla push o unshift
tengo un problema al momento que se agreguen ya sea al principio o al final, si se agregan pero se ordenan por ID, yo estoy buscando que se agreguen a como voy escribiendo ya sea nombre o codigo, al principio unshift o al final push.
este es el codigo donde les muestro donde esta la funcion de agregar los items, donde los tomo de la bd y donde los agrega a la tabla.
function add_invoice_item(t) {
if (1 == count && (spositems = {}), null != t) {
    var e = 1 == Settings.item_addition ? t.item_id : t.id;         
    return spositems[e] ? spositems[e].row.qty = parseFloat(spositems[e].row.qty) + 1 : spositems[e] = t, store("spositems", JSON.stringify(spositems), loadItems(), !0
    
   }

}
function loadItems() {
if (1 == count && (spositems = {}), get("spositems")) {
    total = 0, count = 1, an = 1, product_tax = 0, invoice_tax = 0, product_discount = 0, order_discount = 0, total_discount = 0, $("#posTable tbody").empty();
    
    var t = (new Date).getTime() / 1e3;

    if (1 != Settings.remote_printing) {
        var e = (r = "C: " + $("#select2-spos_customer-container").text() + "\n") + (i = "R: " + $("#hold_ref").val() + "\n") + (l = "U: " + username + "\n") + (c = "T: " + date(Settings.dateformat + " " + Settings.timeformat, t) + "\n") + "\n";
        order_data.info = e, bill_data.info = e;
        var a = "",
            o = ""
    } else {
        $("#order_span").empty(), $("#bill_span").empty();
        
        var n = "<style>.bb td, .bb th { border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD; }</style>",
            s = '<span style="text-align:center;"><h3>' + Settings.site_name + "</h3>",
            r = "<h5>C: " + $("#select2-spos_customer-container").text() + "</h5>",
            i = "<h5>R: " + $("#hold_ref").val() + "</h5>",
            l = "<h5>U: " + username + "</h5>",
            c = "<h5>T: " + date(Settings.dateformat + " " + Settings.timeformat, t) + "</h5>";
        $("#order_span").prepend(n + s + "<h4>" + lang.order + "</h4></span>" + r + i + l + c), $("#bill_span").prepend(n + s + "<h4>" + lang.bill + "</h4></span>" + r + i + l + c), $("#order-table").empty(), $("#bill-table").empty()
    }

spositems = JSON.parse(get("spositems")), $.each(spositems, function() {
            
        var t = this,
        e = 1 == Settings.item_addition ? t.item_id : t.id;     
        spositems[e] = t;   

        var n = t.row.id,
            s = t.row.type,
            r = parseFloat(t.row.tax_method),
            i = t.combo_items,
            l = t.row.qty,
            c = parseFloat(t.row.quantity),
            h = t.row.quantity,
            s = t.row.type,
            d = t.row.discount,
            p = t.row.code,
            u = t.row.name.replace(/"/g, "&#034;").replace(/'/g, "&#039;"),
            m = parseFloat(t.row.real_unit_price),
            _ = t.row.comment,
            g = t.row.ordered ? t.row.ordered : 0,
            f = d || "0",
            v = formatDecimal(f);               
        if (-1 !== f.indexOf("%")) {
            var h = f.split("%");
            isNaN(h[0]) || (v = formatDecimal(parseFloat(m * parseFloat(h[0]) / 100), 4))

        }


El código debe ser corto y preciso, favor agregar un [MCVE]

El problema es la manera en que spositems se renderiza en la tabla o en cómo los datos se están gestionando dentro de la función loadItems().
Lo tienes almacenado como un objeto, lo que puede provocar que los elementos se "reordenen" por sus claves (por ejemplo, por ID).
Si lo almacenas como un array, puedes usar push y unshift sin que el orden cambie automáticamente.
Si se almacena como un array, puedes usar push y unshift sin que el orden cambie automáticamente. Asi:
function add_invoice_item(t) {
    if (count == 1 && (spositems = []), t != null) {
        var e = Settings.item_addition == 1 ? t.item_id : t.id;
        
        // Verifica si el ítem ya existe, si no lo agrega
        var itemExists = spositems.find(item => (Settings.item_addition == 1 ? item.item_id : item.id) === e);
        
        if (itemExists) {
            itemExists.row.qty = parseFloat(itemExists.row.qty) + 1;
        } else {
            // Usa unshift para agregar al principio, o push para agregar al final
            spositems.push(t);  // Cambia a unshift si quieres agregar al principio
        }

        store("spositems", JSON.stringify(spositems));
        loadItems();
    }
}

Tambien loadItems para asegurarte de que spositems sea tratado como un array:
function loadItems() {
    if (count == 1 && (spositems = []), get("spositems")) {
        total = 0;
        count = 1;
        an = 1;
        product_tax = 0;
        invoice_tax = 0;
        product_discount = 0;
        order_discount = 0;
        total_discount = 0;
        $("#posTable tbody").empty();

        spositems = JSON.parse(get("spositems"));

        // Asegurarse de que no haya reordenamiento
        spositems.forEach(function(t) {
            // Lógica de renderizado aquí para cada item
            // Usa el orden en que se almacenan en el array
            var n = t.row.id;
            var s = t.row.type;
            var r = parseFloat(t.row.tax_method);
            var i = t.combo_items;
            var l = t.row.qty;
            var c = parseFloat(t.row.quantity);
            var p = t.row.code;
            var u = t.row.name.replace(/"/g, "&#034;").replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
            var m = parseFloat(t.row.real_unit_price);
            var _ = t.row.comment;

            // Inserta cada ítem en la tabla sin reordenar
            // Aquí puedes usar tu lógica de renderizado en la tabla
        });
    }
}

Asegurate también que en la tabla donde renderizas los elementos no haya alguna configuración o propiedad que reordene los elementos automáticamente, como en un plugin de tabla o alguna función de sort en el HTML o JavaScript.

Hola si ya agregue spositems.unshift(t); y desafortunadamente no da resultado aún.

He reformulado la solución y he añadido código mejorado. Tu pregunta es buena. No olvides marcarla como aceptada si la solución es clara y funciona como se esperaba.
